# Winston log to file not working

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I use Winston for logging:

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new(winston.transports.Console)(),
        new(winston.transports.File)({filename: '/var/log/logF.log'})
    ]
});
```

and I write to this log:

```
logger.log("File: " + path + " was found");
```

For some reason, the file `/var/log/logF.log` isn't updated, and also the standard output isn't shown the log.

How do I use it so the log will be written in '/var/log/logF.log'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You haven't specified a log "level", and "log" is unfortunately not a default level.
Try:

```
logger.log("info", "File: was found");
// or
logger.info("File: was found");
```

Comment: How I set the log to `.log` level?

Comment: @OrSmith There's no "log" level I think. You have to use [one of these pre-defined ones.](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#logging-levels) Or you could [define your own](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#using-custom-logging-levels) but I think you can't define the level manually to be "log" either, as it'll mess up the default `.log()` function and it won't work.

Comment: I'm not completely 100% sure about this, I only remember running into this exact kinda issue and getting frustrated and just ending up not overwriting the "log" level at all. Feel free to experiment but I'd just go with using "info" or some other level.

Comment: log level is to distinguish severity. Per (rfc5424|https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5424) there is no log level. Think about that: what does "log" level mean? What level of severity does it signal?

Answer (score 5):

After trying and made severals tests with severals advanced logging mechanisms (incl. winston, bunyan, log4js), it appears that loggers are not able to write into file if you do a clean exit `process.exit(0)`.
Removing clean exit solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's pretty lame that we cannot use the process.exit(0) clean exit when a logger is writing to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue this evening. However, I realized the file location wasn't being resolved. I'm not sure if this will solve your issue.

```
filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "add_your_relative_path/error.log")
```